# I can not use Session In Page_Load and I got error below

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, visual-studio-2008-sp1, pageload

why i got this error :

> Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.

when i put this code in my page_load.:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     BackEndUtils.OverallLoader();

     string Teststr = Session["Co_ID"].ToString();
}
```

==========================================================================

this session is made when user logins to my web site and this session works in other areas...

thanks for your attention

==========================================================================

thanks for your answers

i removed `BackEndUtils.OverallLoader();` but error still exists

i tried `Teststr = Convert.ToString(Session["Co_ID"]);` and error disappeared - but i don't know why that session is null

in other areas that session works perfectly = such as a button in that form

what is the matter?

my web page markup is like this :

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Admin/AdminBackend.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Personel.aspx.cs" Inherits="Darman.Admin.Personel" Theme="DefaultTheme" %>
```

=================================================================================

i put this code in a button like this :

```
string Teststr = Convert.ToString(Session["Co_ID"]);
```

when i press that button THIS code in page Load(POSTBACK) + IN Button_Click works perfectly and shows me 23 (my Co_ID)

But when i run my page in browser (first time) this code in page load shows me null.

why?

thanks a lot

Comment: thanks for your attention
"click the tick mark next to it" -> what is the name that mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
Teststr = Convert.ToString(Session["Co_ID"]);
```

which will handle `null`s; also check: have you got session-state disabled for the page?

```
<%@ Page language="c#" ... EnableSessionState="false" %>
```

(although I would have perhaps expected a more obvious error in that case)

Comment: but why Session["Co_ID"] is null ? should n't.


in other areas it works perfectly

Comment: @LostLord - are they logged in? Is it the same ASP.NET application instance? it is app-pool recycling? Lots of possibilities...

Answer (score 1):

Probably "Co_ID" session parameter doesn't exist. Check before:

```
if (Session["Co_ID"] != null) 
 {
   Teststr = Session["Co_ID"].ToString();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should perhaps see the error. Error says `.ToString()` doesn't work with objects and moreover, you need not to write `.ToString()` here. It will work without it as shown below

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BackEndUtils.OverallLoader();

    string Teststr = Session["Co_ID"].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception could be raised in one of these two conditions:

1. Something in the body of `BackEndUtils.OverallLoader()` raises the exception.
2. For whatever reason `Session["Co_ID"]` is null, and invoking `ToString()` on null fails.

Use the stack trace provided by the exception to determine which one is right. If it is #1 we will have to see the source of that method to do any further trouble shooting. If #2, you might need to do some manual correction around that line in your code (you might want to do that anyway):

```
object id = Session["Co_ID"];
if (id == null)
{
    id = Session["Co_ID"] = LoadCoIdFromSomewhere();
}

string Teststr = id.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

The error may be coming from your `BackEndUtils.OverallLoader`.

As for the session variable - if someone comes to this page *without* logging in, it will not be set. The session might also have timed out and `"Co_ID"` is no longer set.